# Hyperparameter tunning with wandb - CommError: Sweep user not valid when trying to initial the sweep

Tags: python, hyperparameters, mlops, wandb

I'mt rying to use wandb for hyperparameter tunning as described in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/wandb/examples/blob/master/colabs/pytorch/Organizing_Hyperparameter_Sweeps_in_PyTorch_with_W%26B.ipynb?authuser=1#scrollTo=hoAi-idR1DQk) (but using my dataframe and trying to do it on random forest regressor instead).

I'm trying to initial the sweep but I get the error:

```
sweep_configuration = {
    "name": "test-project",
    "method": "random",
    "entity":"my_name"ת
    "metric": {
        "name": "loss",
        "goal": "minimize"
    }
    
}

parameters_dict = {
    'n_estimators': {
        'values': [100,200,300]
        },
    'max_depth': {
        'values': [4,7,10,14]
        },
    'min_samples_split': {
          'values': [2,4,8]
        },
    
    'min_samples_leaf': {
          'values': [2,4,8]
        },
    
    
    'max_features': {
          'values': [1,7,10]
        },

    }

sweep_configuration['parameters'] = parameters_dict

sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep_configuration)
```

> 400 response executing GraphQL. {"errors":[{"message":"Sweep user not
> valid","path":["upsertSweep"]}],"data":{"upsertSweep":null}} wandb:
> ERROR Error while calling W&B API: Sweep user not valid (<Response
> [400]>)
> CommError: Sweep user not valid

My end goal : to inital the sweep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

- Like in the notebook, you should pass `project="your-project-name"` like `wandb.sweep(sweep_configuration, project="your-project-name")`
- Have you logged in to W&B (using `wandb.login()`)?

Finally, once you've successfully created the sweep, you should pass the `sweep_id` and your function (here `train`) like:
`wandb.agent(sweep_id, train, count=5)`